# Need help getting started with GUI creation/displaying info from variables

Tags: java, user-interface

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9959263
Still trying to get the hang of Java. I've put a TODO tag on the last parts i'm still having trouble with. If I could just get some help going in the right direction that would help a lot. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

[Trail: Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

Try here for a tutorial on making a GUI in java. You can also look at JavaFX, it's the replacement for swing in java 8.